# Use gsub to extract the first integer number

Tags: r, regex, gsub

I'd like to use `gsub` to remove characters from a filename.

In the example below the desired output is 23

```
digs = "filepath/23-00.xlsx"
```

I can remove everything before 23 as follows:

```
gsub("^\\D+", "",digs)
[1] "23-00.xlsx"
```

or everything after:

```
gsub("\\-\\d+\\.xlsx$","", digs)
[1] "filepath/23"
```

How do I do both at the same time?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We could use `|` (OR) i.e. match characters (`.*`) till the `/` or (`|`), match the `-` followed by characters (`.*`), replace with blank (`""`)

```
gsub(".*/|-.*", "", digs)
[1] "23"
```

---

Or just do `parse_number`

```
readr::parse_number(digs)
[1] 23
```

Answer (score 3):

You can just use a `sub` like

```r
sub("^\\D+(\\d+).*", "\\1", digs)
# => [1] "23"
```

See the [R demo](https://ideone.com/YgcYBg). See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/36Asu8/1). *Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `\D+` - one or more non-digit chars
- `(\d+)` - Group 1 (`\1` refers to this group value): one or more digits
- `.*` - any zero or more chars as many as possible.